# W3C: <noscript> in meta refresh alternative

Tags: javascript, meta-tags, noscript

To guide people without javascript activated i added a refresh meta in a  function at my html 4 site:

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://url.com/nojs" /></noscript>
```

I checked W3C validation and they said, this is not allowed.

So my idea was to put a div on top of my site that covers the whole site with a "Please activate Javascript" notification and hide it by default by javascript.

That works perfect. My only problem is, what google thinks about that. So it might look like i would hide the whole content behind a div, and also the first thing google will see is the "Please activate Javascript" notification.

What would you do? Just place the  function in the header and don´t care too much of W3C, or do the "cover-the-whole-site" thing?

Mmm....

Comment: What do you mean with HTTP location header?

Comment: You have much to learn about [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_protocol). :)

Comment: Looks like... i read something about to load the whole site via javascript, because the site isnt usable at all without that activated. But than google will see nothing at all? I understand the redirect method, i think the problem here is the <noscript> tag...

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific in your use case for me to give a concrete answer, but meta-redirects are *never* really a good idea.

Comment: That particular tag in that position is now valid in HTML 5.

Answer (score 2):

The *real* W3C and Google approved way to do redirects is with an [appropriate HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) and a [`Location` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers#Responses). Anything else is a hack to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found a solution:

I placed the `<noscript>` in my footer, set up a div with 100% with and height and an absolut position and a z-index of something really big ;)

So Google first will read my content and at LAST the No-Script notification.

What do you think?

Comment: You could add a nofollow property to the HTML element which holds your javascript-notification to tell the robots to ignore this part. I'm currently thinking about the same solution. Usually I wanted to redirect via noscript, because javascript is needed to scroll down to a sub-page in an one-page solution with real urls per sub-page.